# Is there a way to suggest label names in org-mode latex export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

In the org-mode example below, I would like to be able to specify the label name to be used by the latex export back-end. Is there such a way?

I have two reasons:

1. To be able to mix org-style references [[fig:label]] and latex-style references \ref{fig:label} in the same document. This is not necessary (in fact, probably bad practice) if I have everything in the org document. However, sometimes I \input{} an external latex block with a \ref{} somewhere, so I need to control the named reference.
2. Whenever I export my document, I will get a different latex label (here: orgee8497f). This will have my git back-end think that the document has changed, when in fact it hasn't.

Org source:

```
This is some text. Here I can refer to Figure [[fig:label]]. However,
if I try to refer to \ref{fig:label}, I get an undefined reference.

#+CAPTION: This is a caption to the figure.
#+NAME: fig:label
\begin{figure}
  figure stuff goes here
\end{figure}
```

Latex export:

```
This is some text. Here I can refer to Figure \ref{orgee8497f}. However,
if I try to refer to \ref{fig:label}, I get an undefined reference.

\begin{figure}
  figure stuff goes here
\caption{\label{orgee8497f}
This is a caption to the figure.}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the variable `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` to something non-nil (you can use `customize` to do it). The doc string of the variable says:

> Use user-provided labels instead of internal ones when non-nil.
>
> When this variable is non-nil, Org will use the value of
>   CUSTOM_ID property, NAME keyword or Org target as the key for the
>   \label commands generated.
>
> By default, Org generates its own internal labels during LaTeX
>   export.  This process ensures that the \label keys are unique
>   and valid, but it means the keys are not available in advance of
>   the export process.
>
> Setting this variable gives you control over how Org generates
>   labels during LaTeX export, so that you may know their keys in
>   advance.  One reason to do this is that it allows you to refer to
>   various elements using a single label both in Org’s link syntax
>   and in embedded LaTeX code.
>
> For example, when this variable is non-nil, a headline like this:

```
  ** Some section
     :PROPERTIES:
     :CUSTOM_ID: sec:foo
     :END:
  This is section [[#sec:foo]].
  #+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
  And this is still section \ref{sec:foo}.
  #+END_EXPORT
```

> will be exported to LaTeX as:

```
\subsection{Some section}
\label{sec:foo}
This is section \ref{sec:foo}.
And this is still section \ref{sec:foo}.
```

> Note, however, that setting this variable introduces a limitation
>   on the possible values for CUSTOM_ID and NAME.  When this
>   variable is non-nil, Org passes their value to \label unchanged.
>   You are responsible for ensuring that the value is a valid LaTeX
>   \label key, and that no other \label commands with the same key
>   appear elsewhere in your document.  (Keys may contain letters,
>   numbers, and the following punctuation: ’_’ ’.’  ’-’ ’:’.)  There
>   are no such limitations on CUSTOM_ID and NAME when this variable
>   is nil.
>
> For headlines that do not define the CUSTOM_ID property or
>   elements without a NAME, Org will continue to use its default
>   labeling scheme to generate labels and resolve links into proper
>   references.
>
> You can customize this variable.