# orgmode latex export: How to create repeatable labels?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

Every time I export org-mode document to LaTeX, most sections get new and unique labels, e.g.,

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:orge0665da}
```

The next time I export the document, the label will change, e.g.,

```
 \section{Introduction}
 \label{sec:orgcd0c5bf}
```

If I want to do a `diff` of the LaTeX documents to a previous version, I get a ton of changed labels that hide the changes I have made to the text. Sometimes this confuses `latexdiff` as well.

Is there a way to ensure that the exported labels are the same between exports? At least for as long as the number of (sub)sections does not change? Set a seed to a random number generator? Write a hook function that returns a label given a section?

I am aware of [Is there a way to suggest label names in org-mode latex export?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44665/is-there-a-way-to-suggest-label-names-in-org-mode-latex-export), that solves the problem for a specific label, but not the (in org-mode) un-labelled sections.

Comment: I don't know of any "official" mechanism to accomplish this and a cursory look through the sources did not produce an "aha" moment on a possible implementation. The only thing I can suggest ATM is `sed`: delete the labels before diffing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you hit on the solution yourself:

> Set a seed to a random number generator?

That seems to work just fine in my limited testing. The function `org-export-new-reference` in `ox.el` does indeed call `random` to generate the reference label.

To seed the random number generator, call `random` with some *string* (it seeds the generator with some value computed from the string). If you want the generator seeded before every single export use the `org-export-before-processing-hook`:

```
(defun seed-random-generator (_) (random "a fixed and unchanging string"))
(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'seed-random-generator)
```

(To be honest, I don't really understand why you'd want to diff the generated LaTeX files instead of diffing the original org files. At least you're not diffing PDFs. :P)

Comment: latexdiff generates documents where additions are marked in blue and deletions in red. That document is helpful to distribute to people that are, eh...diff- and org-ed challenged.

Comment: @NiclasBörlin Oh, yes, `latexdiff` on the generated files **is** a great idea!

Comment: Another point for repeatable labels is when your changes are tracked by e.g. Git: you want to look only at the relevant changes between two commits.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I usually don't commit any automatically generated files to a repository. So, in this case, I'd only commit the org files, not the LaTeX files. The org files don't have these random strings in them, so git handles them just fine.

Comment: I can understand. In some cases, you want to commit the `.tex` files in order they are used by colleagues that don't use Org Mode. Another point for repeatable labels is when you build the PDF files thanks to `latexmk` which will rerun the compilation (even) if (only) the labels have changed.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Good points!